# Twitter API v1.1 integration with Mulesoft

Tags: twitter, mule4

I am building a REST API using Mule, which will integrate with Twitter’s API to perform some analysis on recent tweets. For this, I have to connect to Twitter API v1.1

I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Do I have to use a Twitter Developer account to do this? Or can this be achieved without Twitter dev account?

Since I haven't done worked with Twitter APIs before, any guidance will be a great help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To use Twitter APIs you need to request developer access: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/getting-access-to-the-twitter-api

That's unrelated to consuming those APIs from a Mule application or from something else.